# Flash is always blocked in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, flash, windows-10

I noticed that recently Chrome started blocking flash on a site even when it's manually allowed in the site settings. Probably something has been changed in security policy last days? I completed all steps desribed on [Google Chrome Help](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6258784?visit_id=1-636371888361759456-3849493849&p=ib_blocked_plugin&rd=3%20and) and still have no luck.

I'm running Windows 10, Google Chrome Version 60.0.3112.78 (Official Build) (64-bit)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you running PIA or any other VPN's?

Comment: Got a testable link? Or else how to reproduce your issue?

Comment: Without a link to test & assess, we'll just play 21 questions... Is the site `http://`? or else `https://`? If `http` then, that might be causing the error message. _"...Connection is not secure"_ therefore user must manually accept this warning to enable Flash each time.

Comment: The site works over https. Connection is secure. Unfortunately I can't give you a link due to internal policy

Comment: You can reproduce that on Facebook as well http://prntscr.com/g3lz81

Answer (score 2):

Try:

- Launch chrome
- Navigate to chrome://flags/#prefer-html-over-flash
- The flag is most likely set to Default
- Change the flag to Disabled
- Relaunch Chrome
- Does Flash content display now?

Comment: Yes, everything is fine now. Is there any way how to disable it for site visitors? I suppose there is not any workaround and this is a new Chrome "feature" how to make developers get rid of Flash support on their sites, right? :(